# Spring boot autowire external dependency with further optional dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to autowire an external service which has further optional dependencies.

```
    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService; // external dependency

    @GetMapping(value = "/test-cdl2")
    public ResponseEntity<List<CustomerLightweightDto>> testCdl2()  {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(customerService.searchForCustomerAddressByCin("1931454603"));
    }
```

Here `CustomerService` is an external service. Inside `CustomerService.searchForCustomerAddressByCin` method:

```
    @Autowired(required = false)
    private AddressHistoryRepository addressRepository; // optional

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<AddressHistoryDto> retrieveAddressHistory(String cin) {
        notNull(cin, ERROR_CIN_MISSED.getText());
        log.debug("Retrieve list of address history by cin [{}]...", cin);
        return addressRepository.findByPartyIdOrderByEndDateDesc(findPartyIdByCin(cin));
    }
```

We have `addressRepository` which is defined as an optional dependency.

Now when I try to run `testCdl2`, it throws NPEs. How can i tell Spring to create a bean for nested dependencies?

EDIT:
Already configured the root package of external dependency in `ApplicationConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.my.fsap.aap.customer.data", "com.my.fsap.aap.ldap.security"})
@EnableCaching
@EnableRetry
public class ApplicationConfig {
```

Here `com.my.fsap.aap.customer.data` is the root where the optional dependency is present.

Answer (score 0):

The `AddressHistoryRepository` should be in the Spring Context. To do it provide the bean definition in the configuration that will be scanned by `@ComponentScan`. If you know that Spring has this definition you can add `@ComponentScan` with the package where this definition is. The other way is to create your own definition with `@Bean` annotation.

Comment: The root package is already configured in `@ComponentScan` yet it doesn't work due to optional dependency. I'll try the @Bean approach but it may not be useful as i need to deal with many such optional dependencies.

Comment: @saran3h if a bean definition is in the area of `@componentscan` it should instantiate a bean even for optional dependencies.